# Firefox crashes when attempting to load addon from file

Tags: firefox

Firefox crashes when you attempt to load an addon from a file with the error message "GLib-GIO-ERROR **: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system"

I expect the file manager to launch and have me select an addon file, but firefox just crashes a second later.